# JDialog WindowOpened event is fired just once

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

I'm trying to get the `WindowOpened` event from `JDialog`, but it is fired just once.
Why `windowClosing` works correctly and `WindowOpened` just once? Is there any way to fire the open event for `JDialog` every time?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class NewClass extends JDialog {

    public void init() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setModal(true);
        setSize(100,100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void addListener() {
        addWindowListener(
            new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Invoking WindowOpened from JDialog");
            }
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Invoking WindowClosing from JDialog");
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main( String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(200,70);

        final NewClass d = new NewClass();
        d.init();
        d.addListener();

        JButton b = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                d.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        f.getContentPane().add(b);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried WindowActivated? WindowOpened works when it's opened for the first time.. WindowActivated works everytime your window is activated. And change your dialog to JFrame, this way you can minimize your window.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara  *"And change your dialog to JFrame.."*  This is not a good move.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: I agree @AndrewThompson, but he didn't say that he was using multiple windows. There's nothing wrong in having a frame... It could also be a Main Frame.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara The code already has one frame.  Also the dialog is modal.  A second frame instead of the dialog would be a nightmare.  BTW - your answer is essentially correct.  I especially like the use of `@Override` as a sanity check on the method signature.  Why did you delete it?

Comment: You're right about the JFrame that he created.. I didn't read the entire code, my mistake... I deleted because it was unecessary, as long as I could post as a comment.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your answer. I made a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: +1 for posting an SSCCE.  Glad you got the problem solved with the advice of Gabriel.  :)

Comment: Ok, Andrew, you got the point. :D Thanks for yours efforts to teach :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.windowActivated(e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

[ComponentListener#componentShown(ComponentEvent e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent)) is fired whenever your Window is made visible.

I don't believe WindowActivated is a good choice (like others said) because it can be fired in some others circumstances. For instance, if your Dialog is not modal, WindowActivated will be fired whenever the window regains focus.